# Execute Overridden Method From Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have two classes like below (I tried to abstract example as I can):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo1
{
public:
    foo1() {};
    virtual ~foo1() {};
    void Method1()           { Method2(); }
    virtual void Method2()   { cout<<"parent";}
};

class foo2 : public foo1
{
public:
    virtual void Method2()  { cout<<"child";}
};

int main()
{
    foo2 a = foo2();
    a.Method1();
}
```

I received "parent" message. So `Method1()` of `foo2` executes `foo1::Method2()`.

What I need to use in order to make that `foo2::Method1` invokes their `foo2::Method2`?

Comment: How about a fully pure virtual `Method2`?

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect the code above to print "child".

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors in your code, it prints `child` as expected: [Demonstration](http://ideone.com/2bEHQM). If your code does something else, then please post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'd expect the code above to refuse to compile.

Comment: Destructor in base class should be `virtual`.

Comment: It is good that you tried to simplify the example, but you should make sure that what you post actually reproduces the effect you claim to see, let alone compile.

Comment: I made  a fairly extensive edit here to make the example compilable, and the question a little clearer.  Hope I didn't change the intent.

Answer (score 9):

No you don't, you get `"child"`. You'd get parent if you did

```
foo1 a = foo2();   // My crystal ball tells me this is what you really have
```

which would be due to object slicing. To get it to work, you'd need either pointers or references:

```
foo2 f;
foo1& rf = f;
rf.Method1();   //child
```

or

```
foo1* a = new foo2();
a->Method1();   //child
```

Comment: right now i am posting a question : "Where to get crystal ball which allow great replies on SO".

Comment: @UmNyobe you get one when your each 10k :P

Comment: @UmNyobe:  He's lying.  I got a crystal ball at 10K, but it was cracked and doesn't do crap.